# Excel - calculating durations of time data

Tags: excel

I'd like to find the duration of each transaction.

```
      A        B        C        D       E    F

2015-01-02  08:05:34  DEBUG:  operation  C1  begin
2015-01-02  08:06:35  DEBUG:  operation  C1  end
2015-01-02  08:01:35  DEBUG:  operation  C2  begin
2015-01-02  08:08:36  DEBUG:  operation  C2  end
2015-01-02  08:09:36  DEBUG:  operation  C3  begin
2015-01-02  08:10:36  DEBUG:  operation  C3  end
```

assume my raw data is in columns A, B, C, D, E and F, with headings in row 1, and data starting in row 2 I want to produce a result set as follows:

```
Operation Title, Duration
operation C1 , 00:01:01
operation C2, 00:07:01
operation C3, 00:01:00
```

After I Add a new column, G , titled Duration with a formula that like this :

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(F1)="B",INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(F1,F2:F6,0))-B1,""),"")
```

But I have an error invalid function.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy alternative.

In **G2** enter:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,B2-B1,"")
```

and format **G2** as *h:mm:ss*.  Then copy **G2** downwards:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for response. but, I have a error invalid function. my question is   : are the special configuration in excel? thank you in advance.

Comment: I have error message '' The formula you typed contains an error. ''